# Include Tier Prices in Price Range on Catalog Listing Page

Tags: performance, magento-1, tierprice

For a configurable product with price differentials, Magento's catalog listing page (the page where Magento displays a list of products), <s>prices can be displayed as a range</s>

<s>`$35.23 - $64.00`</s>

(**Update**: Stock Magento can't display prices as a range.)

However, this range doesn't not incorporate (or does not appear to incorporate) price possibilities based on tiered pricing.

Is there a canonical/sane (ideally performant) way to get these price ranges to include the lowest/highest price including all tiered price options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused - when you say "prices can be displayed as a range" do you mean Magento can be configured to display the range? I can't find any setting that would do that (in 1.9.1), so I am assuming you are doing the range generation yourself.

Maybe :

```
$tierPrices = array();
// returns an array when no qty is passed 
$tierInfo = $product->getTierPrice();

/* use afterLoad for load tier price to product object whenever 
            product collection does not contain tier price in collection-*/

if (is_null($tierInfo)) {
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
    if ($attribute) {
        $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
        $tierInfo = $product->getData('tier_price');
    }
}


if (is_null($tierInfo)) {
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
    if ($attribute) {
        $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
        $tierInfo = $product->getData('tier_price');
    }
}

foreach ($tierInfo as $tierPrice) {
    array_push($tierPrices, $tierPrice['price']);
}
$maxTier = max($tierPrices);
$minTier = min($tierPrices);
```

Then push the $maxTier and $minTier into the array of prices you are creating the range from, or compare them against the existing high / low values?

Of course, this could be totally off base depending on how the range is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up -- I'd assumed the price range was a built-in feature.  I hadn't realized it was hacked into the template by other people's code.

Comment: I'm used to seeing it as well, I assumed the same thing. Thought I was taking crazy pills when I couldn't find it.